# Finding the correct EPSG for multiple UTM zones

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I am currently trying to transform projections in R in the sf package. However, my dataset that contains animal movement tracks from 26 different individuals contains observations in the WGS84 UTM zones ranging between WGS84/UTM 14N to WGS84/UTM 19N.

Is there a suitable reference system specific for this range or what would be the recommendation in regards to CRS for this data range?

I am relatively new to EPSG codes, so I am just trying to find a way for the future to determine the most suitable coordinate reference systems.

Comment: If you have more than three UTM zones of information, you shouldn't use UTM. Place it all in an appropriate Albers or Lambert Equal Area instead. Or use WGS84 geographic and be prepared to calculate distances via geodesic functions.

Comment: Which country is your data in? Does it have a national or regional projection?

Comment: The data is from marine animals and ranges from off the coast of Texas through the Gulf of Mexico and along the US Atlantic coast up to New York.

Comment: @Vince: ok, will look it up. I need to get the data into a projected coordinate system in meter units to be compatible with the package I need for the next analysis steps.

Comment: Use the USGS CONUS Albers (EPSG 5070 or 6350) for US mapping.

Comment: @Vince - perfect, thank you!

Comment: Note that EPSG code is not synonymous with code for CRS.  Not all CRS have EPSG codes. and EPSG codes apply to more spatial objects than just CRS ~ see EPSG.org